# How to properly aggregate Decimal values in a django app: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'aggregate'

Tags: python, django, decimal, django-tables2, django-money

I'm in a [django-tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) `Table`, trying to compute the sum of a column (based on a `MoneyField` ([`django-money`](https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) in the model, see hereunder):

```py
import django_tables2 as table

class PriceAmountCol(table.Column):
    # print(f"Total price is: {record.price.amount}")
    # print(f"Type of total price is: {type(record.price.amount)}")
    def render(self, value, bound_column, record):
        total_price = record.price.amount.aggregate(
            total=Sum("price")
        )

Class MyTable(table.Table):
    # Fields
    price = PriceAmountCol(
        verbose_name=_("Price [EUR]"),
    )
    #...
```

But this error is raised:

```
  File "/code/djapp/apps/myapp/tables.py", line 192, in render
      total_price = record.price.amount.aggregate(
AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'aggregate'
```

If not commented out, the two `print` instructions give:

```py
Total price is: 112.80
Type of total price is: <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

But the value `112.80` is only the first one of the table. There are some others.

How could I properly aggregate price values (`Decimal`) in my current table column?

The field in the model is as follow:

```py
    price = MoneyField(
        default=0.0,
        decimal_places=2,
        max_digits=12,
        default_currency="EUR",
        verbose_name=_("Price [EUR]"),
    )
```

#### Version info

django 4.2.8
djmoney 3.4.1
django-tables2 2.7.0
python 3.10.6

#### Related information

https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-headers-and-footers.html#adding-column-footers
[Django-tables2 column total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701875/django-tables2-column-total)
[Django-tables2 footer sum of computed column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216880/django-tables2-footer-sum-of-computed-column-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replacing the `render()` function by:

```py
class PriceAmountCol(table.Column):
    total_price = 0
    def render(self, value, bound_column, record):
        self.total_price += value
        return value
```

seems to work. So there is no need to use `.aggregate`.

But this solution is maybe(?) less efficient.